# Weird caching issue with ASP.net/Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms

I'm writing an application involving storing a profile. I'm using Linq to access the database, but having a weird issue when saving a profile. When I save it, it writes to the DB correctly - but when I leave the page and come back, the old values still remain in profile form.

My profile page:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack) {
    Profile p = Student.GetProfile(Int32.Parse(Session["userID"].ToString()));
    if (p != null)
    {
          FirstNameTextBox.Text = p.FirstName;
          LastNameTextBox.Text = p.LastName;
          Address1TextBox.Text = p.Address1;
          .....
    }
```

And my Student class:

```
    public static Profile GetProfile(int uID)
    {
        var profile = (from p in db.Profiles
                       where p.uID == uID
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();
        return profile;
    }
```

I'm not doing any fancy caching anywhere, so not sure where the old values are stored...

** EDIT **

So, it seems that it's down to a global LinqDataContext.  In my Student class, I had:

```
public class Student
{
    private static LinqClassesDataContext db = new LinqClassesDataContext() { CommandTimeout = 36000 };

    public static Profile GetProfile(int uID)
    {
            var profile = (from p in db.Profiles
                           where p.uID == uID
                           select p).FirstOrDefault();
            return profile;   
    }
```

If I give the GetProfile method it's own DataContext, problem solved.

Still being very new to Linq, what's the best way to have a class with numerous methods that use the same access to a database?  Having a global context like this?  Or each method using it's own data context?

Comment: Just for clarity, are you saying the new values appear in your db when you query it but once you navigate away, then back, the old values are back in the db?

Comment: The correct value gets updated in the db - and stay there. But when I navigate away from the page and come back, it's as if it doesn't query the db again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're storing the `userID` in `Session["userID"]` somewhere and not clearing it out when you save, this could be where the "caching" occurs.  `Session` objects will live (roughly) for the life of the browser session (or the life of the server process if in-memory session is enabled).

Comment: The userID wouldn't change when saving the profile, so I'm not sure how that would cause the problem.

Comment: I'm not saying it changes, I'm saying _it's still in the session_, so when you reload the page it will still load the ID from the session.  Since you didn't show where you set (or clear) that session variable I assumed you're not clearing (or changing) it.

Comment: Further testing shows that when I log out (and the session is destroyed) and log back in, the old/cached values are still filled into the form.

Answer (score 0):

i guess even if linq send the query to the database it use the old value stored in the cache.so you have to clear the cache if you want the new value.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why it's caching to begin with. When the page loads, it should look up the current values in the db... which it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Going on your added comments my guess is that the page you are getting is cached by the browser / http server. If the url is the same as a previously requested page some default setting will tell the browser / server to use the cache html. To avoid this and get new html for each request you could try adding a meta tag within the head tags of your html.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
```

Comment: I thought it might be browser related, but even after doing hard refreshes, it's still pulling the old data.  Have added this, but doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Whenever I rebuild the site, it loads the correct information.

Comment: I'm running Chrome, and I have caching turned off in the browser for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the DataContext I was using.  I'm not exactly sure why this fixed the issue, but I changed my class from:

```
public class Student
{
   private static LinqClassesDataContext db = new LinqClassesDataContext() { CommandTimeout = 36000 };

   public static Profile GetProfile(int uID)
   {
        var profile = (from p in db.Profiles
                       where p.uID == uID
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();
        return profile;   
   }
}
```

to:

```
public class Student
{
   public static Profile GetProfile(int uID)
   {     
        LinqClassesDataContext db = new LinqClassesDataContext();
        var profile = (from p in db.Profiles
                       where p.uID == uID
                       select p).FirstOrDefault();
        return profile;   
   }
}
```